# How do i transpose and grouping in PL/SQL [ORACLE]

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
SELECT 
    USER, 
    DEP
FROM Table_1;
```

| USER | DEP |
| --- | --- |
| USER1 | DEP1 |
| USER2 | DEP2 |
| USER3 | DEP2 |
| USER4 | DEP3 |

But i want to transpose it and group user under `DEP`.

| DEP1 | DEP2 | DEP3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | USER2 | USER4 |
| USER3 | NULL | NULL |

What i have tried following pivot query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
( 
    SELECT 
        USER,
        DEP
    FROM Table_1
) AS NewTable
PIVOT
(
  MAX(USER)
  FOR DEP IN ([DEP1],[DEP2],[DEP3])
) AS pvt;
```

The output is: `00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"`.

How do i use `PIVOT` properly?

Comment: Wrapping identifiers in `[]` is not valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: PL/SQL is the programming language, SQL is the query language. This question seems to be about queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give each `DEP` type a row number and then pivot:

```sql
SELECT dep1,
       dep2,
       dep3
FROM   (
  SELECT "USER",
         dep,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY dep ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   table_1
)
PIVOT (
  MAX( "USER" )
  FOR DEP IN (
    'DEP1' AS dep1,
    'DEP2' AS dep2,
    'DEP3' AS dep3
  )
)
ORDER BY rn
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 ( "USER", DEP ) AS
SELECT 'USER1', 'DEP1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'USER2', 'DEP2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'USER3', 'DEP2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'USER4', 'DEP3' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DEP1  | DEP2  | DEP3 
> :---- | :---- | :----
> USER1 | USER2 | USER4
> null  | USER3 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=59b64acf7c681898fcd1c3df311cfdcd)*